# How do programmatically store the sharepoint document library document to local machine?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, .net

i have one question. How do pro-grammatically store the sharepoint document library document(eg Image.png) to local machine(D:/Images)?? Anybody have a solution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010app");
var web = context.Web;
var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");
var items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var stream = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, (string)item["FileRef"]).Stream;
    var filename = string.Format("d:\\images\\{0}", item["FileLeafRef"]);
    using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filename))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: error:"System.IO.Stream does not contain the definition for 'CopyTo' and no extension method 'CopyTo' accepting a first argument type of System.IO.Stream could be found"

Comment: `CopyTo` requires .Net 4, if you're using earlier version then see [How do I save a stream to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)